# Combine files as handy as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x

Combine files as handy as possible

Suppose I have the following markdown files

```
    1.md # contains 'foo'
    2.md # contains 'bar'
    3.md # 'zoo'
    4.md # 'zxc'
```

They are easy to be merged using command `cat`

```
$ cat {1..4}.md > merged_5.md
```

Nevertheless, Python requires multiple steps to achieve this result.

1. Create Read and Write Methods

   ```
   def read(filename):
       with open(filename) as file:
           content = file.read()
           return content
   def write(filename, content):
       with open(filename, 'w') as file:
           file.write(content)
   ```
2. Retrieve the qualified files

   ```
   import glob
   filenames = glob.glob('*.md')
   In [17]: filenames
   Out[17]: ['1.md', '2.md', '3.md', '4.md']
   ```
3. Read and combine

   ```
   def combine(filenames):
       merged_conent = ""
       for filename in filenames:
           content = read(filename)
           merged_content += content
       write('merged.md', merged_content)
   ```
4. Encapsulate data and methods in `main` module and save as 'combine_files.py'

   ```
   def main():
       filenames = glob.glob('*.md')
       combine(filenames)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```
5. Run it on command line

   python3 combine_files.py

It's not handy as command 'cat'

How to refactor the codes to be as handy as possible?

Comment: You could write a `cat` function that does exactly that, except rather than be 760 lines of pure C, and thousands of lines of dependency code for GNU Coreutils, is... 4 lines of code. How's that for "handy".

Comment: `subprocess.call('cat {1..4}.md > merged_5.md', shell = True)` :P I mean, use the right tool, what does "handy" even mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like?:

```
with open('merged.md', 'w') as out_f:
    for filename in glob.glob('*.md'):
        with open(filename) as f:
            out_f.write(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just do the easy:

```
def cat(out, *src):
    '''Concatenate files'''

    with open(out, 'wb') as f:
        data = b'\n'.join(open(i, 'rb').read() for i in src)
        f.write(data)
```

You may now call it with `cat('merged.md', glob.glob('*.md'))`. How's that for handy? Certainly much easier than the source of GNU Coreutils.